# bulk upload video files from URL to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3

After some googling it appears there is no API or tool to upload files from a URL directly to S3 without downloading them first?

I could probably download the files locally first and then upload them to S3. Is thee a good tool (Mac) that lets me batch upload all files in a given directory?

Or are there any PHP scripts I could install on a shared hosting account to download a file at a time and then upload to S3?

Answer (score 0):

The **[AWS Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)** can upload files to Amazon S3, eg:

```
aws s3 cp file s3://my-bucket/file
aws s3 cp . s3://my-bucket/path --recursive
aws s3 sync . s3://my-bucket/path
```

The [`sync`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command is probably best for your use-case. It can synchronize local files with remote files (only copy new/changed files), or use `cp` to copy specific files.